# How to create a referral link in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to figure out a way to create a unique referral link that directs to my site for each user that signs up. But to be sincere, I don't really know how it works out for sure. I have tried googling but couldn't find a perfect answer. Any plugin needed or any way around that?

*The user model, not much code I don't have any idea of this*

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    referralLink: String
})

UserSchema.plugin(passortLocalMongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema )
```

**User sign up**

```
router.post("/register", function(req,res){
    var newUser = new User({username: req.body.username,referral: req.body.referral});
                    
    User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function(error, user){
        if(error){
            console.log(error)
            req.flash("signerror", error.message)
            return res.redirect("/register")
        }
        //Do the referral link creation stuff here, don't know for sure
            
    }) 
})
```

*If there is a way to solve this then I would be glad for any help*

Comment: You can check this article, it may help you https://itnext.io/build-a-referral-system-in-node-express-and-postgres-da56fa4913d4 i'm putting the url for you , because this top can take a lot of discussion and i think the best way is to read the full article then decide if it helps you or not

Answer (score 13):

### How to create a referral link?

Let this be a platform/language agnostic *how-to*:

- Every time new User is created, generate unique link for him to be his unique referral link and store it in DB (For simplicity this could be `_id` which is unique in MongoDB and is auto-generated - in this case you don't have to create another field). Let's also keep count of how many people registered through this person's link, let it be `referredCount`.

  Referral link could look for example like this: `/register?referrer=${_id}`, where ${_id} is user unique ID.
- Send referral link to user, so he can pass it along to other people, or make it visible in his `/account` page - obvious step
- When someone registers via this link, create new User as usual and after succesful creation, get `req.query.referrer` from the URL, look into DB for user with this particular ID and increase his `referredCount`.

Note that it's just a way of doing that, I'm sure there might be many different strategies for it.

Comment: Thanks for the nice idea, i think am gonna have a bit knowledge of how to create the link, though if you find something new about this, don't forget to draw my attention @TomaszBubala

Comment: I am still encountering issues with it, by default I made it to redirect to home page, the problem is that when a user clicks on another link in the page e.g (about page), the referral link is gone. Any idea how i can make it persist in the route for the user session. @TomaszBubala

Comment: @FillipoSniper, You can check my answer.

Comment: Hello Fillipo, ou need to redirect to the register/signup page, where you have your signup form, and not the about us page.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you create a table/collection for referrals.
Schema could contain:

- userId (the user who generated the link)
- numberOfUses (the number of times the link can be used)
- expires at (incase you want to limit the validity to a specific period)

MongoDB will generate a _id aka `referralId`

You can modify the registration endpoint to accept an optional param `referralId`

Whenever someone uses a referal you just get the userId of the person who created the invite link.

Answer (score 0):

To address Your question from the comment:

You can follow @Tomasz suggestion however to keep referral link You can use cookies.

A cookie is a small piece of data which is stored in a user’s web browser when they visit a website. When a customer comes to your website via an affiliate referral link (i.e. yoursite.com/?ref=123), application should store two main browser cookies in order to track the referring affiliate, and the visit. Their names are:

- **aff_ref** - this cookie stores the affiliate's unique ID
- **aff_ref_visit_id** - this cookie stores the visit ID (the visit ID increments by 1, each time any referral link is used until the cookie expires or is deleted).

So You are able to detect if user came to website using referral link by checking the cookie. It is worth to mention that
cookies should remain in the browser throughout the purchase or conversion process to track the correct affiliate so a referral can be generated for that affiliate. The cookies should also remain in the customer's browser for a period of time specified by the site admin or until the customer clears their cookies.

Comment: thanks I already found a way to add a persistent cookie which holds the referrer unique ID, and I check the value on users signUp :)

Answer (score 0):

in the user schema .. have a field named referral (either be a name, number or takes another user's Id ) ...on the main site. create a button that will generate a user's personal referral link (using Javascript) so that the link will look like "your-domain.com/register?register=${user._id} ... then on the registration page ... there will be an hidden input field ... which will automatically be field with the query param ...
`location.search` so that when a user register ... the person that referred them will also be registerd ... then the route will be like

```
app.post('/register',(req,res) =>{
  user.update({id:(req.query.register)},{referral:req.body.name})
...remaining registration routing ... 
})
```